# Assign a different design for each ul

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have the following web page :

[image]

I have a problem with the customized ul, I can't find a method to assign for each ul a specified design like above (circle, icon, /*/, square)

This is my html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style7.css" />
</head>
<body>

<h2>Plan d'études du semestre 1 en TC</h2>

<ol type="I"  >

  <li>Mathématiques appliquées 1
  <ul class="a"> Mathématiques appliquée 1
  <ul>
  <li> Cours:2h </li>
  <li> TD: 1h </li>
  </ul>
  </ul>
  
   
  <ul class="a"> Atelier Mathématiques appliquées1
  <ul>
  <li> TP: 1.5h </li> 
  </ul>
  </ul>
  </li>

<li>Algorithmique et structures de données
  <ul class="a"> Algorithmique et structure de données 1
  </ul>
  </li>



<li>Programmation structurée
  <ul class="a"> Langage de programmation
  </ul>
  <ul class="a"> Atelier programmation structurée
  </ul>
  </li>




<li>Architecture et système 1
  <ul class="a"> Architecture des ordinateurs
  </ul>
  <ul class="a"> Systèmes logiques
  </ul>
   <ul class="a"> Atelier Architecture et Systèmes 1
  </ul>
 </li>






  <li>Développement Web et multimédia 1
  <ul class="a"> Programmation Web1
  <ul>
  <li> Cours:1h </li>
  <li> TD:0.5h </li>
  </ul>
  </ul>
  </li>
   
  <ul class="a"> Atelier développement web et multimédia 1
  </ul>
  


<li>Culture et langues
  <ul> <u>Anglais technique 1</u>
  </ul>
  <ul class="b">C2i-l
  </ul>
  <ul> <u>Français1</u>
  </ul>
  <ul class="b"> Droit de l'homme
  </ul>
 </li>

</ol>


</body>
</html>
```

and this is my CSS code :

```
.a {
  font-style: italic;
 
 list-style-type: circle;
 
}

.b {
  font-style: initial;
 
}


ol > li {
color: red;
font-style:initial;
}

ol li ul{
   color: black;
  
   font-style: italic;
   
 
}

ul li {
   color: blue;
   list-style-type: disc;
   font-style:initial;
}
```

This is what I get :

[image]

Comment: It's not completely clear what your problem is. Please be more precise in your description and state what the desired output should be vs. what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select each list style you should use the pseudo element :nth-child. For the actual icon to be changed you can use list-style-type: for normal symbols like square, disc ect. However for custom icons that are not available you can use list-style-image: url();
For examples check out this [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp) guide. Hope this helped!

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this if u use 'list-style-image' for UL tag.
Please refer below sample.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_list-style-image